# Poisson process - Probability of waiting time for first arrival at least 1 hour.

Tags: probability, poisson-process

Suppose that the number of trucks arriving at a depot per day is a random variable having a Poisson distribution with $\lambda = 28.8$. What is the probability that the time between two arrivals is at least 1 hour?

This seems similar to part (b) of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283648/poisson-distribution-mean-time-and-probability-of-waiting).

---

My attempt:

This is the same as the probability of the first arrival (after 9AM say) being at least 1 hour later.

I thought that it would be
$$\int_{1/24}^\infty 28.8 e^{-28.8t}dt = e^{-1.2} \approx .3012,$$
but the answer in the back of the book is $.1827$ instead.

"Another" attempt:

An average of $28.8/24 = 1.2$ trucks arrive per hour. Let $P(x;\lambda)$ be the probability distribution of a Poisson random variable. Then we want $$P(0; 1.2) = \frac{1.2^0e^{-1.2}}{0!} = e^{-1.2} \approx .3012.$$

---

As an aside, I'll mention that I think this exercise is flawed because presumably, the rate at which the trucks arrive would be different in the middle of the day than in the middle of the night.

Comment: Some truckers prefer to travel at night because of lower traffic, however others prefer to travel during the day so they can retain a normal schedule

Comment: looks like a mistake or typo somewhere in the book, $0.1827 \approx e^{-1.7}$ instead of $e^{-1.2}$, go figure which number they messed up

Comment: @Pavlov Well, I have found several obvious typos in the book.

Comment: @NickPavlov If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.